# How to check for string in log file and move file to different folder according to status using batch

Tags: batch-file

I am having a log file.

I need to loop through the entire file in batch script and if the file contains the text `226 Transfer complete` I need to do following:

1. write to log file `File complete`;
2. move the file to different directory;

How can I do that with a batch script?

Comment: Do you really mean DOS or are you referring to the Windows command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findstr /L /c:"226 Transfer complete" "yourlogfilename" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
 echo File complete>logfile
 move "the file" "destination directory\"
)
```

Not that hard...

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the Windows command line, which you probably are, here's what you can do:

```
@echo off
type myfile.txt | findstr /C:"226 Transfer Complete"
if errorlevel 0 echo File Complete >> log.txt
```